# Materialize index throws DB::Exception: Missing columns

Tags: clickhouse

I met a problem for `materialize index` with version 21.3.

I create a table with 3 coulmns `u64`, `i32` and `s`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_idx (`u64` UInt64, `i32` Int32, `s` String) ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY u64;
```

Then I insert 3 millions data in it and run `OPTIMIZE TABLE test_idx FINAL`(to make part `Wide`)

```sql
select name, part_type from system.parts where table='test_idx' and active=1;
┌─name──────────────────┬─part_type─┐
│ all_1_21762_111_21773 │ Wide      │
└───────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Then I add tow indexes to the table

```sql
alter table test_idx add INDEX a (u64, s) TYPE minmax GRANULARITY 3;
alter table test_idx add INDEX b (i32 * length(s)) TYPE set(1000) GRANULARITY 4;
```

Then I materialize the index `a` to make the index useful for old data.

```sql
alter table test_idx materialize index a;
```

Here's the Exception and stack trace.

```
2022.07.14 04:06:38.192403 [ 11633 ] {} <Error> DB::IBackgroundJobExecutor::jobExecutingTask()::<lambda()>: Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Missing columns: 'i32' while processing query: 'u64, s, i32 * length(s)', required columns: 'u64' 's' 'i32' 'u64' 's' 'i32', Stack trace (when copying this message, always include the lines below):

0. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/poco/Foundation/src/Exception.cpp:27: Poco::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0xe16fb61 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
1. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../src/Common/Exception.cpp:55: DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int, bool) @ 0x476f358 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
2. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../src/Interpreters/TreeRewriter.cpp:752: DB::TreeRewriterResult::collectUsedColumns(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST> const&, bool) (.cold) @ 0x416fba2 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
3. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/libcxx/include/new:237: DB::TreeRewriter::analyze(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IAST>&, DB::NamesAndTypesList const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IStorage const>, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, bool, bool) const @ 0xa8a1228 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
4. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/libcxx/include/list:753: DB::MergeTreeDataMergerMutator::getIndicesToRecalculate(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::IBlockInputStream>&, DB::NamesAndTypesList const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::Context const&) @ 0xac80bbb in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
5. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/libcxx/include/list:753: DB::MergeTreeDataMergerMutator::mutatePartToTemporaryPart(DB::FutureMergedMutatedPart const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::MutationCommands const&, DB::BackgroundProcessListEntry<DB::MergeListElement, DB::MergeInfo>&, long, DB::Context const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<DB::IReservation, std::__1::default_delete<DB::IReservation> > const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&) @ 0xac87d74 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
6. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/libcxx/include/type_traits:3934: DB::StorageMergeTree::mutateSelectedPart(std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::StorageInMemoryMetadata const> const&, DB::StorageMergeTree::MergeMutateSelectedEntry&, std::__1::shared_ptr<DB::RWLockImpl::LockHolderImpl>&) @ 0xaaf12d2 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
7. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../src/Storages/StorageMergeTree.cpp:967: bool std::__1::__function::__policy_invoker<bool ()>::__call_impl<std::__1::__function::__default_alloc_func<DB::StorageMergeTree::getDataProcessingJob()::'lambda'(), bool ()> >(std::__1::__function::__policy_storage const*) @ 0xaaf15dc in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
8. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../src/Storages/MergeTree/BackgroundJobsExecutor.cpp:103: void std::__1::__function::__policy_invoker<void ()>::__call_impl<std::__1::__function::__default_alloc_func<DB::IBackgroundJobExecutor::jobExecutingTask()::'lambda'(), void ()> >(std::__1::__function::__policy_storage const*) @ 0xabefd13 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
9. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/libcxx/include/functional:2212: ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<ThreadFromGlobalPool, void*>) @ 0x47cd3a2 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
10. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../src/Common/ThreadPool.h:181: ThreadFromGlobalPool::ThreadFromGlobalPool<void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda1'()>(void&&, void ThreadPoolImpl<ThreadFromGlobalPool>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda1'()&&...)::'lambda'()::operator()() @ 0x47cd84e in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
11. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/libcxx/include/functional:2212: ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::worker(std::__1::__list_iterator<std::__1::thread, void*>) @ 0x47ccb42 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
12. /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/../../contrib/libcxx/include/memory:1655: void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void ThreadPoolImpl<std::__1::thread>::scheduleImpl<void>(std::__1::function<void ()>, int, std::__1::optional<unsigned long>)::'lambda1'()> >(void*) @ 0x47cb4f3 in /root/zyf/workspace/clickhouse/build/RelWithDebInfo/bin/clickhouse
13. start_thread @ 0x8609 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so
14. __clone @ 0x11f133 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.31.so
 (version 21.3.14.1.7)
```

Column `i32` is not used for index `a`, but why here shows `Missing columns`? Or I can't use skipping index in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of ClickHouse should resolve your issue. Is there any specific reason for you to use 21.3?

Comment: I make a development on 21.3 for many reasons. So upgrading to the latest version may cause unknown problems. But maybe using the latest version will more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try detach all the data parts that causes the error (assuming that the MATERIALIZE mutation had succeeded on most data parts), and attach them to a new table with same structure, do MATERIALIZE on the new table, and hopefully it will complete with no error. Finally `ALTER TABLE ... MOVE PARTITION ...` to move all partitions back to the old table.